# Will Redshift UNLOAD succeed despite broken connection?

Tags: postgresql, jdbc, amazon-redshift

Simple and probably obvious question but can't seem to find an answer.

### Question

Will a query stop when a JDBC connection breaks?

Some queries, like `SELECT`, definitely should but what about `COPY` or `UNLOAD`?

### Use case

I want to have a fleet of tiny AWS Lambdas that do `INSERT INTO SELECT`, `CREATE`, `UNLOAD` and `COPY`. These won't return anything and all instructions should be within the cluster.

Comment: Please experiment and let us know what you discover!

Comment: @JohnRotenstein Tried with pg8000. On the Lambda timeouts query continues but it's the transaction is rolled-back shortly after finishing query. Will do a few more experiments.